# GRPC call failing with error "Received unexpected EOS on DATA frame from server."

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I am using GRPC to connect to a service. Sometimes calls are successful, while sometimes it fails with exception `Received unexpected EOS on DATA frame from server.`

I am not able to find the reason to this. Following is code making call:

```
public class LmServiceClientImpl implements LmServiceClient {

    LMAttributeServiceGatewayGrpc.LMAttributeServiceGatewayBlockingStub lmAttributeServiceGatewayBlockingStub;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("lmservice")
    private ManagedChannel managedChannel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        lmAttributeServiceGatewayBlockingStub = LMAttributeServiceGatewayGrpc.newBlockingStub(managedChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public LMAttributesApiProto.IpAttributeResponse getAttributes(
            final LMServiceProto.IpEntityRequest ipEntityRequest
    ) {
        try {
            log.info("Querying DLM service with payload {}",
                    JsonFormat.printer().print(ipEntityRequest.toBuilder()));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // No action required
        }
        final LMAttributesApiProto.IpAttributeResponse ipAttributeResponse =
                lmAttributeServiceGatewayBlockingStub.getAttributes(ipEntityRequest);

        try {
            log.info("Response from DLM service {}", JsonFormat.printer().print(ipAttributeResponse.toBuilder()));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // No action required
        }
        return ipAttributeResponse;
    }
}
```

The ManagedChannel is getting autowired from following class:

```
public class LmServiceGrpcConfig {

    @Value("${lm.server.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${lm.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean("lmservice")
    public ManagedChannel prepareManagedChannel() {
        return NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Client dependencies:

```
def grpcVersion = '1.26.0'
compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.44.Final'
    compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-protobuf', version: "${grpcVersion}"
    compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-stub', version: "${grpcVersion}"
    compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-services', version: "${grpcVersion}"
    compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-okhttp', version: "${grpcVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.5.1'

    compile group: "io.github.lognet", name: "grpc-spring-boot-starter", version: "3.4.1"
```

Server is in golang and uses `google.golang.org/grpc v1.25.1`

Not sure what is causing the issue. Please help. I have seen some posts on github issues regarding this, but that didn't help.

Comment: this means the server is sending unexpected http2 frame (protocol violation). can you provide server information (what language, version of grpc etc). or, it can be a misbehaving proxy in the middle.

Comment: Server information:
GRPC version is: google.golang.org/grpc v1.25.1
Server is in golang

Client information:
Language: Java
Dependencies: added in question description.

@creamsoup it will be really great if you help me resolve this.

Comment: can you confirm proxy is used or not? it is most likely proxy causing the issue. unfortunately, proxy related issues are hard to verify.

Comment: @creamsoup we are using istio-proxy which internally uses envoy.

Comment: sorry, i don't have enough knowledge of proxy to help. at least you have some idea where to investigate :) probably proxy drops connection under some condition?

Comment: Thanks @creamsoup. Will post the solution if I am able to resolve this.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but please see my answer @RajatMishra

Answer (score 0):

I believe this message means that the request timed out. Envoy is cutting the stream short by sending the message "End of Stream" (EOS).

On the server, you might also see something like this:

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.http2.PeerClosedStreamException: Stream with ID [15655] was closed by peer with code NO_ERROR(0x00)
```

According to[`request_timeout` Envoy documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager-request-timeout):

> This timeout is not compatible with streaming requests.